# Issues when monitoring a gluster FS mount with Nagios via sudo

Tags: nagios, sudo, glusterfs, nrpe

I have been monitoring a gluster FS mount with the following script, but have issues executing the script via NRPE.

Here's my script on the remote box.
/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_gluster.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

@output=`/usr/sbin/gluster volume heal static info split-brain | egrep "Number of entries"`;

if($output[0] !~ m/0/){ 
        print "CRITICAL: Possible m4_2b split brain issues - $output[0]";
}elsif($output[0] !~ m/0/) {
        print "CRITICAL: Possible m4_2c split brain issues";
}else {
        print "OK";
}
```

In my NRPE, I have the following configuration

```
command[check_glusterfs]=/usr/bin/sudo /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_gluster.pl
```

When I run check_nrpe on Nagios, I have the following:

```
# /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -t 60 -H myhost.domain.com -c check_glusterfs
NRPE: Unable to read output
```

On the remote box, I have the following  error,

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1397547577.720:1183140): avc:  denied  { execute } for  pid=20524 comm="sh" name="sudo" dev=xvde ino=11029 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:nrpe_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:sudo_exec_t:s0 tclass=file
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1397547577.720:1183140): arch=c000003e syscall=59 success=no exit=-13 a0=89f800 a1=89ecd0 a2=89e1f0 a3=7fff72151910 items=0 ppid=20523 pid=20524 auid=512 uid=497 gid=498 euid=497 suid=497 fsuid=497 egid=498 sgid=498 fsgid=498 tty=(none) ses=120914 comm="sh" exe="/bin/bash" subj=unconfined_u:system_r:nrpe_t:s0 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1397547577.720:1183141): avc:  denied  { execute } for  pid=20524 comm="sh" name="sudo" dev=xvde ino=11029 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:nrpe_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:sudo_exec_t:s0 tclass=file
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1397547577.720:1183141): arch=c000003e syscall=21 success=no exit=-13 a0=89f800 a1=1 a2=0 a3=7fff72151910 items=0 ppid=20523 pid=20524 auid=512 uid=497 gid=498 euid=497 suid=497 fsuid=497 egid=498 sgid=498 fsgid=498 tty=(none) ses=120914 comm="sh" exe="/bin/bash" subj=unconfined_u:system_r:nrpe_t:s0 key=(null)
```

[Updated]
Anyone has any idea how I can resolve this? Unfortunately, I am not allowed to disable selinux on the box.

I am running Cento 6.5

Regards,
Alan

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that SELinux blocks Nagios plugins which use sudo.

To make sure this is caused by SELinux you can disable it or set it to permissive:

```
/etc/sysconfig/selinux
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#       enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#       permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#       disabled - SELinux is fully disabled.
SELINUX=permissive
```

The policy change will work on next boot.

Comment: I am not very familiar with SElinux, could you advise how I can add the policy?

Comment: updated my answer on how to disable or set selinux to permissive instead

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot disable or set it to permissive....Were there some problems with the previous answer?